# Is singleton pattern unavoidable in CMS-like apps?

Tags: php, content-management-system, singleton, dependency-management

In a CMS app, like WordPress, the CMS only loads plugins, and the plugins then request their dependencies (like database, configs etc) from the CMS, which acts like a registry.

I haven't seen a CMS app written in PHP that doesn't use this pattern (or anti-pattern). They all use a registry in one way or another, for example:

```
craft()->request->getPost('id')  (craft)
```

or

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert($table, $data);   (wp)
```

or

```
$db = Database::getConnection();  (drupal)
```

or

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();  (joomla)
```

Therefore, is it right to say that singleton patterns are unavoidable for this type of application?

Comment: You can use Dependency Injection to avoid singletons. This is often coupled with a Factory to create objects.

Comment: I'm aware of that, its just that no cms uses di, and I was wondering if the reason for this is because it's not possible because of the nature of a cms

Comment: I expect _some_ CMS apps use DI. If you want to know why WordPress does not, maybe ask the core devs?

Answer (score 1):

> Therefor singleton patterns are unavoidable for this type of applications, right?

I can't say that this is straight forward.
Singleton is a design pattern, not a requirement.
In fact, most developers are implementing design patterns without even knowing.
I bet that if someone will try real hard, he'll find a way to completely avoid Singleton.
Im not sure why this is bothers you. but that's the best answer I can provide.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of (maybe all?) content management systems use this object orientated php programming since it is the cleanest and nicest way to code. Of course it is possible to avoid it, but the code doesn't stay that structured any more.

If you find that strange you should learn how to use it and you will see that it's a very clean way to code.

More information can be found here:

> http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762

and here:

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php